# Google Compute Engine, Managed Instance Group, Autoscaler with custom metric wrtitten from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I want to use the Autoscaler for Managed Instance Groups with a custom metric I write to from App Engine.

However the Autoscaler documentation states:

> The standard metric must contain data for a gce_instance monitored resource. You can use the timeSeries.list API call to verify whether a specific metric exports data for this resource.

Can I create the metric as type "gce_instance" and write to it from GAE? Or did I misinterpret the documentation section and I can just go ahead without special consideration for this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google App Engine (GAE) users should use "[global](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_global)" as a resource type because the resource type gae_app is not permitted in custom metrics. You are good to create custom metric as "global" and write to it from GAE. You can find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource) as a reference.